# How to view SQL Server queries run in WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I  have an Asp.Net 3.5 WebForms application. Is there any way to see queries run by the application? Something like Glimpse for MVC, maybe.

Thanks.

Comment: Library advice is off-topic, and the [Glimpse docs](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/) are pretty clear I think? :)

Comment: I did not find Glimpse for .Net 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the query being sent to the server, using [SQL server profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx).

You can also log the query manually during debugging in your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask how I can filter out in Profiler all the queries that I am not interested in? There are thousands of them there, so I cannot find what I need.

Comment: @DavidShochet you can filter by database, or even table.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have this information. I need to see the query to find out.

Comment: @DavidShochet what do you know about the query? the filter tool is really flexible https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175061.aspx